# How to scroll table in non-scrolling page (airtable) via selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a problem with parsing this page-https://airtable.com/appImi8PX0i84XFwj/shr1PWZhR25O6DJxK/tblJG95RoC1WrRppF/viwVAi9l6dxxBtihM. I need to get all data from the table, but i cant scroll it! I have already tried to scroll just with js in console but it doesnt work

p.s. i know this is similar question([Python script to scroll down non scroll-able page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695690/python-script-to-scroll-down-non-scroll-able-page))  but it doesnt help in my case

**this is my python code **

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def get_html(url):
    service = Service(executable_path='C:\\airtable_parse\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe')
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()

    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(10)

        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table"]').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN) #Message: element not interactable
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()

        #driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#table').scrollTop = 500")

        # table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="firstContainer"]')
        # print(table)
        # action = ActionChains(driver)
        # action.move_to_element(table).perform()
        # print(action)
        # driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 300)', table)

        # while True:
        #     # After your page is loaded
        #     page_hight = driver.get_window_size()['height']  # Get page height
        #     scroll_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'antiscroll-scrollbar-vertical')]")
        #     ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(scroll_bar, 0, page_hight - 160).click().perform()
        # #driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 100);')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


def main():
    get_html("https://airtable.com/embed/appImi8PX0i84XFwj/shr1PWZhR25O6DJxK/tblJG95RoC1WrRppF/viwVAi9l6dxxBtihM")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

there are a lot of attempts in my code. Also my js code -
`document.querySelector("#view").scrollTop=300 document.querySelector("#viewContainer").scrollTop=300 document.querySelector("#table")`

i think i need this html element (
that's not accurate)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1: intercept the response(about 7MB) of following request and decode it

https://airtable.com/v0.3/application/appImi8PX0i84XFwj/read?stringifiedObjectParams=%7B%22includeData ...

#### Solution 2: simulate mouse wheel event(scroll/scrollBy/scrollTo does not work for this website)

I tried this method using puppeteer(page.mouse.wheel) and it can work.

Comment: The first solution has a problem: all keys in json are unique